# Перестали работать Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Год назад сделал приложение под андроид для "путешествия" по улицам в гугл. API, ключи (с выставлением НЕ применения ограничения для ключа)... всё работало прекрасно. И вот, запустив через год на том же телефоне ту же мою установленную ранее, работавшую программу (как и на двух других) теперь высвечивается чёрный экран и ... ничего. (о разрешениях, я, естественно, в курсе). Причём другая моя программа с гугл картами (изображение спутника, обычная карта) работает прекрасно, но та где хождение по улицам - уже нет. Как вернуть себе своё? Я понятия не имею, по какой из миллиона причин у меня теперь чёрный квадрат, но эта программа мне очень нужна для дальнейшей работы. Компьютер и ПО осталось тем же без каких либо обновлений, но это не важно, т.к. даже сама программа на телефоне теперь стала тю-тю. Меня терзают смутные сомнения, что тут пованивает от гугла и его смертоносных обновлений, т.к. иногда, вместо отображения карты, мне выдаётся сообщение: "Сервисы google play необходимые для работы с приложением не поддерживаются на данном устройстве" (на плей маркет я не выставляю). Буду очень рад любой толковой идее. (Есть одно НО - вариант переустановки Android Studio КАТЕГОРИЧЕСКИ не подойдёт!)

```
_______________________________________
Ошибка при загрузке проекта (до запуска)

16:03:08 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
16:03:08 * daemon started successfully
16:03:39 FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in /C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/idea.jar

____________________________
Ошибки после запуска (для отладки я использую реальный телефон )

12-31 17:30:22.822 21435-21435/com.example.user.googlestreetview13 E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
12-31 17:30:23.259 21435-21435/com.example.user.googlestreetview13 E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
12-31 17:30:25.899 21435-21489/com.example.user.googlestreetview13 E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-31 17:30:25.901 21435-21489/com.example.user.googlestreetview13 E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                              Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                              Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                                API Key: AIzaSyAfnpeUXjFFd*****7jw93SauFQmbSjIc
                                                                                                Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 2D:BA:0D:FD:8D:2F:EB:99:DF:BE:***:FC:34:44:55:E7:8D:1D;com.example.user.googlestreetview13
____________________________
Моя программа (не важно, что кособокая, суть проблемы в полном отсутствии ранее работавшего проекта)

MAINACTIVITY____________

package com.example.user.googlestreetview13;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanorama;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaCamera;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaOrientation;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {
    StreetViewPanorama streetView;
    StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewFragment =
                (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        streetViewFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
        streetView = streetViewPanorama;
        streetViewPanorama.setPosition(new LatLng(47.517487, -122.20154330000000));
        streetViewPanorama.setStreetNamesEnabled(false);
        streetViewPanorama.setPanningGesturesEnabled(false);
        streetViewPanorama.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
        streetViewPanorama.animateTo(
                new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder().
                        orientation(new StreetViewPanoramaOrientation(20, 20))
                        .zoom(streetViewPanorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
                        .build(), 2000);
    }

    public void oCl(View view) {
        StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera  = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                .tilt(-30)
                .bearing(-30)
                .build();
        streetView.animateTo(camera,-10);
    }

    public void oCg(View view) {
    }

    public void oCr(View view) {
    }
}


MANIFEST______________

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.googlestreetview13">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ptrprograms.streetview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAfnpeU****dR_g7jw93SauFQmbSjIc">
        </meta-data>
    </application>

</manifest>

GRADLE 1 ___________
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.googlestreetview13"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32@aar'
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'

GRADLE 2 _________

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема скрывалась в Гугле и его нововведении в виде платного использования API. При переходе на платную/кредитную форму программа сразу же заработала.